# How to run code in a separate thread?

Tags: scala

I want to spawn a thread and run code in that thread. What are the options in Scala?

Example usage would be something like this:

```
Thread.currentThread setName "MyThread"

val myThreadExecutor = ???

val threadNamePromise = Promise[String]

future {
  myThreadExecutor run {
    val threadName = "MySpecialThread"
    Thread.currentThread setName threadName
    threadNamePromise success threadName
  }
}

Await.result(threadNamePromise.future, Duration.Inf)

future {
  myThreadExecutor run {
    println(Thread.currentThread.getName) // MySpecialThread
  }
}

future {
  myThreadExecutor run {
    println(Thread.currentThread.getName) // MySpecialThread
  }
}

println(Thread.currentThread.getName)   // MyThread
```

Is there anything in the built-in Scala library that I can use?

### Edit

I updated the snippet to better reflect intent

Comment: The `ops` object is depreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [the answer of @alexwriteshere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15773992/596816) as a basis I created this implementation:

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.future
import scala.concurrent.JavaConversions.asExecutionContext

class ApplicationThread {
  protected implicit val context = 
    asExecutionContext(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

  def run(code: => Unit) = future(code)
}
```

---

**Update**

Thanks to @Dth for pointing out that this is the modern version:

```scala
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import scala.concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Future}

class ApplicationThread {
  protected implicit val context = 
    ExecutionContext.fromExecutorService(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

  def run(code: => Unit) = Future(code)
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Yes, there is. You can use the `scala.concurrent` from the standard library. More specifically, you can use futures - highly composable asynchronous computations.

```
import java.util.concurrent.Executors
import concurrent.{ExecutionContext, Await, Future}
import concurrent.duration._

object Main extends App {

  // single threaded execution context
  implicit val context = ExecutionContext.fromExecutor(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

  val f = Future {
    println("Running asynchronously on another thread")
  }

  f.onComplete { _ =>
    println("Running when the future completes")
  }

  Await.ready(f, 5.seconds) // block synchronously for this future to complete

}
```

Futures run in an execution context, which is an abstraction for thread pools. This context can be passed implicitly. In the above example, we used a global one, defined by the Scala library - but you can control this aspect of your program by allocating many execution contexts.

The snippet only does what you asked - running code concurrently. However, futures are much more than that - they allow you to compute values asynchronously, compose multiple futures to obtain results with dependencies amongst them, or in parallel.

Here's an intro: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/futures.html

Comment: I know about `Future`, the thing is, I want to inject pieces of code from multiple threads into a single thread that will then execute those pieces of code.

Comment: You mean, you want to generate tasks from multiple threads and send those tasks to a another thread which executes them ?

Comment: future is deprecated (i'm in 2.11)

Answer (score 2):

Besides the standard concurrency library, there's a few more. For example, there's `com.twitter` / `util-core` library that lets you do:

```
val pool = FuturePool.unboundedPool
pool {
   <code>
}
```

Your example would look like:

```
Thread.currentThread setName "MyThread"

// because you have to be using a single-threaded one to get the same name
val pool = FuturePool(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())

pool {
  Thread.currentThread setName "MySpecialThread"
}

pool {
  println(Thread.currentThread.getName) // MySpecialThread
}

println(Thread.currentThread.getName)
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into the source code to see how they did it. It seems though as this is a Java solution and not a Scala based one

Comment: It's written in scala and is just an alternative library. See the other answer for scala's standard library which offers a similar way to handle futures.

Comment: Using your answer I was able to create [a simple solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15774778/596816).

Answer (score 1):

Based on [@EECOLOR](https://stackoverflow.com/users/596816/eecolor)'S [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15774778/5125206), here's a generic, reusable method that executes arbitrary code on a separate thread:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

def executeParallelTask[T](code: => T): Future[T] = Future(code)
```

Comment: With current version of Scala this is a better approach. However, instead of using `Implicits.global` it's better to add an extra parameter list: `(implicit ec: ExecutionContext)`. This gives the caller the choice to select a context. Instead of writing this function I would recommend just using `Future(code)` (less code and less indirection).

Answer (score 0):

```scala
ExecutionContext
  .fromExecutorService(Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor())
  .execute(() => {
    // your code here
  })
```